# in books, TV, or films?

Tags: parallelism

I'm wondering whether the phrase 'in books, TV, or films' is correct.
It seems to realize the 'in A, B, and C' structure; however, the preposition
'in' does not go with 'TV'. We cannot say 'in TV'.

Do we have to say 'in books, on TV, or in films' instead?

Comment: How about *... in books, TV shows, or films ...*?

Comment: 'in books or films, or on TV'

Comment: Related: [How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this parallel structure need coordinated prepositions to avoid being a faulty parallelism?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133671/does-this-parallel-structure-need-coordinated-prepositions-to-avoid-being-a-faul)

Comment: Worrying about this sort of thing (except perhaps in "learned" journals where the P-ists hang out) is being excessively anal.  It is quite common to be forced by the nature of English to construct a "parallel" structure which is not quite as parallel as one would like, and, while one should certainly avoid this when avoidance is easy, distorting the rest of the sentence to "solve" the problem is far more distracting to the reader than simply accepting a smidgen of imperfection.

Comment: And who says you can't use "in TV"?  What rule forbids that construct?

Comment: 'He's something big in TV' sounds fine to my ears. But I'd never use 'Almost everybody  must have encountered hobbits this in books, TV, or films'.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, it is correct.**  However, if *on TV* sounds better, you can say 'in books or films, or on TV' instead.

The phrase 'in books, TV, or films' is fine to use.  Consider using the unabbreviated word *television*.  Also, see the question, "[Is "In movie and TV" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291906/is-in-movie-and-tv-correct)" which shows that you can say "in television" or (in TV.)

Comment: To me this seems wrong, I have never heard anyone talk about what's ***in** TV*, always **on**. Also, the use of TV over television is completely normal. Edit: see this [Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=TV%2CTelevision&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTV%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTelevision%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey What is *on* TV is more of the programs and channels.  What is *in* television is more like the content as a whole (its reoccurring themes, symbolism and morals.) See [on TV, in TV Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+TV%2Cin+TV&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Comment: I'd disagree, based solely on personal experience - so I shan't be too harsh - I have never heard what is *in TV*. However this may be an AmE/BrE split. Also it seems that the *on* usage as you put it is what the OP wants.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey That's true.  It's like saying "on yesterday" or just "yesterday."

Comment: You wouldn't say "in TV", but in this context, where TV is an item in a list, I think it's acceptable.  It could also be interpreted as "in **the domain of** books, TV, and films", in which case it's not incorrect at all.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey There is no AmE/BrE split here **at all**.  However,  "ïn TV", only works if referring to the industry, as in: in theater.